# Lookup search duplicate values and return alternate column value

Tags: excel, excel-formula, pivot-table

I am using O365.

[image: Setup]

I am attempting to transform the data in A:D to the format of F:K and I'm stumped asking for help.

My first formula in H2 is:

```
=INDEX(C:C,MATCH(1,(A:A=F2)*(C:C="*Dental*"),0))
```

This returns #N/A. What am I getting wrong? Return Col C matching the row where EE code is F2 and Plan contains "Dental".

The Plan will always include either "Dental" or "United".

My thought would then be to use the values in F2 and H2 to lookup the coverage value for that EE+Plan in Column I and K.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Edit:

```
=INDEX(C:C,MATCH(1,(A:A=F2)*(IFERROR(SEARCH("*Dental*",C:C),0)),0))
```

This formula solves my problem.

Comment: How many groups of `EE Codes` might there be?

Comment: There is about 500 unduplicated EE Codes in total (Column F) and the original list (Column A) has around 1000 with duplications.

Comment: I guess I wasn't clear:  Can one EE code have more than one duplicate (i.e three or four)

Comment: Up to 4. I was actually able to retrieve what I wanted by switching the partial text to (IFERROR(SEARCH("*Dental*",C:C),0))

Comment: `(C:C="*Dental*")` does not do a wild card match.  It is looking for the exact string.  You can do `(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Dental",C:C)))`

Comment: This can be done fairly easily with Power Query, especially if you can provide the details of all the various column headers.

Comment: Although I have solved my issue by altering the formula, I'd certainly be interested in a PQ method. Not asking you to write it out, but do you have any resources I can check out?

Comment: @spacej3di See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I expanded your example a bit

[image]

If you have O365 then you should be able to do the following.

`H2 =XLOOKUP($F$2:$F$5&"Dental*",$A$2:$A$7&$C$2:$C$7,C2:C7,"<not found>",2)`

`I2 =XLOOKUP($F$2:$F$5&"Dental*",$A$2:$A$7&$C$2:$C$7,D2:D7,"<not found>",2)`

`J2 =XLOOKUP($F$2:$F$5&"United*",$A$2:$A$7&$C$2:$C$7,C2:C7,"<not found>",2)`

`L2 =XLOOKUP($F$2:$F$5&"United*",$A$2:$A$7&$C$2:$C$7,D2:D7,"<not found>",2)`

This will also let you know if are missing any elections.

You can also list all of the unique EE Codes using `F2 =UNIQUE(A2:A7)`.

[XLOOKUP](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/xlookup-function-b7fd680e-6d10-43e6-84f9-88eae8bf5929)

Answer (score 1):

In Power Query, one can:

- Group By `EE Code` and `EE`
- Then combine the coverage/plan type columns in the group so as to be able to split into separate columns.

**M Code**

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table13"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"EE Code", type text}, {"EE", type text}, {"Plan", type text}, {"Coverage", type text}}),
 
//Group by EE code and EE
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Changed Type", {"EE Code", "EE"}, {{"Grouped", each _, type table [EE Code=nullable text, EE=nullable text, Plan=nullable text, Coverage=nullable text]}}),

//Exapnd the Grouped columns to create a text string which can be split into the relevant columns
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "Custom", each 
        List.Combine(
            List.Zip({Table.Column([Grouped],"Plan"),Table.Column([Grouped],"Coverage")}))),
    #"Extracted Values" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Added Custom", {"Custom", each Text.Combine(List.Transform(_, Text.From), ";"), type text}),

//This line will need modification if your order of coverage varies; or if the types of coverage are different
    #"Split Column by Delimiter" = Table.SplitColumn(#"Extracted Values", "Custom", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter(";", QuoteStyle.Csv), 
        {"Dental Plan", "Dental Coverage", "Health Plan", "Health Coverage"}),

//Remove unneeded column
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Split Column by Delimiter",{"Grouped"})
in
    #"Removed Columns"
```

Results from your data:

[image]

The mcode will need modification if there are other types of coverages or if the coverage types are not in the desired order.  See the comments in the code